# Is there a way to use the #define directive to create a constant struct?

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have this struct

```
typedef struct 
{
    int AM;
    char* name, surname;
}Item;
```

and I want to define a constant NULLitem with AM = -1 and NULL name/surname. Is there a way to do it with #define?

Comment: Note that the `surname` is a single character, not a pointer.  Moving the `*` next to `char` doesn't make it apply to `surname`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What is the reason for this? Is it the case with all type of pointers? When declaring more pointers in one line, the asterisk applies only to the first one?

Comment: What if one of those fields is set null and the others not? Suggest maybe have 1 field that is a key?

Comment: @IstvánCsige: The syntax of C declarations is unusual.  See [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7).  A declaration consists of a list of 'declaration specifiers' (such as a type name) followed by a list of (possibly initialized) 'declarators'.  The `*` in a pointer is part of the declarator notation, not part of the declaration specifiers.  So, in `char *name, surname`, the declaration specifier is `char`, and the first declarator is `*name` and the declarator is `surname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define NULLitem (const Item){ .AM = -1, .name = NULL, .surname = NULL }
```

That's a C99 [compound literal](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5).

Comment: There is a minor issue. This construct cannot be used as initializer for static objects, not without compiler extensions. `static Item item = NULLitem;` would be technically illegal.

Comment: @tstanisl — if you poke GCC hard enough with `-pedantic` (I used `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic`) — then you do indeed get a warning that " initializer element is not constant".  Without `-pedantic`, it doesn't complain even with those fairly stringent warning options.

Comment: You could define two macros: `#define NULL_ITEM_INITIALIZER { .AM = -1, .name = NULL, .surname = NULL }` and `#define NULLitem (const Item)NULL_ITEM_INITIALIZER`.